# according to this code is this language a typed or untyped language?

Tags: computer-science, typing, type-systems, strong-typing, static-typing

I have this code in my HW and it doesn't mention what language it is , and the questions are below the code I am new to the expressions so I'm a little confused , I will be happy to get some help answering or helping with the questions:

```
x = 3; 
s = read_string_input(); 
if (isnumber(s) and strToInt(s) > 0) 
x = s + 1.3; 
else 
x = "negative input";
print(x);
```

the questions are:

1. is it a typed language ?
2. is it strong or weak typing language?
3. is it dynamic or static language?
4. is it implicit or explicit typing?

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to first determine was a "typed" language is? That information alone should help you figure out the answers to the rest of the questions.

Comment: I totally agree with you , I didn't ask here before I searched the net and tried to solve it alone. I'm not sure of what i have understood if it's really the right answers to the question above. and here I'm asking really for a help. iam not seeking a solution rather than an explanation. thanks anyway ..

Comment: A typed language, in my view, is one where each variable (such as `x`) is assigned the type of data it will hold, be it a string, integer, boolean, etc. So in an example like `x=3`, it could be assign an integer value. But if that type of value changes, such as in `x="some text"`, then the `x` value has not been locked to a certain type of data. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems like a typed language because of `strToInt` and `isnumber`-methods. In an untyped language you wouldn't have to convert values to use them at all.
2. It is a weak typing language, because one does not seem to need to cast anything to any other type, but instead can assign values all around as seems necessary.
3. It seems to be a dynamic language, because the object does not necessarily have to be of a certain type beforehand.
4. It looks like an implicit typing conversion, because types seem to be deducted from the values they are expected to contain.

By the way: it looks somewhat like JavaScript (except neither **const**, nor **let**, nor **var** is used when defining a variable).

Still: the excerpt looks a bit small in order to be able to tell for sure.

For instance the variable `x` could have been defined as a type, which allows strings and integers alike and `isnumber` as well as `strToInt` could contain instanceof checks and converters (e.g. taking a String and creating an integer in order to return it instead of implicitly returning an integer).

Sources: Knowledge, Google, https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/10/03/static-vs-dynamic-typing-of-programming-languages/, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ATyped_and_untyped_languages.